# facet_zoom by date range from stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, summary, stat, ggforce

I am trying to zoom into a specific date range but the code below is not allowing me to do so. Also in this plot are stat_summary by `Bleach` and an existing facet by `Species`. I am willing to zoom into each species as separate plots if that is a workaround but I've tried subsetting by species and am still unable to produce the desired result.

```
structure(list(ColonyID = c("11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "238", "238", 
"238", "238", "238", "238", "238", "239", "239", "239", "239", 
"239", "239", "239"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Montipora capitata", 
"Porites compressa"), class = "factor"), Bleach = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bleach", 
"Non-bleach"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(18096, 18155, 
18171, 18185, 18199, 18285, 18501, 18096, 18155, 18171, 18185, 
18199, 18285, 18501, 18096, 18155, 18171, 18185, 18199, 18285, 
18501, 18096, 18155, 18171, 18185, 18199, 18285, 18501), class = 
"Date"), 
ColorScore2 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L)), row.names = c(3L, 43L, 83L, 123L, 163L, 203L, 243L, 
4L, 44L, 84L, 124L, 164L, 204L, 244L, 34L, 74L, 114L, 154L, 194L, 
234L, 274L, 35L, 75L, 115L, 155L, 195L, 235L, 275L), class = 
"data.frame")

a <- ggplot(test, aes(x = Date, y = ColorScore2, color = Bleach)) + stat_summary(aes(group = 
Bleach), fun = mean, geom = "point") + stat_summary(aes(group = Bleach), fun = mean, geom = 
"line") + scale_color_manual(values = c("Bleach" = "gray", "Non-bleach" = "black")) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Bleach" = "gray", "Non-bleach" = "black")) +. 
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b", limits = as.Date(c("2019-07-01", 
"2020-02-01"))) + facet_grid(. ~ Species) + labs(y = "Bleaching Score", x = "Date") +. 
theme_bw() 
b <- a + facet_zoom(x = Date >= "2019-09-16" & Date <= "2019-10-30")
```

Comment: Try `facet_zoom(x = Date >= as.Date("2019-09-16") & Date <= as.Date("2019-10-30"))` also your `test` `dput()` is wrong as it causes errors!

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the same result. It isn't zooming properly and is eliminating the existing facet by ```Species```. The ```dput``` should be fixed - sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You code may have some issues:

1. I removed `limits = as.Date(c("2019-07-01",  "2020-02-01"))` and use `filter(Date >= as.Date("2019-07-01"), Date <= as.Date("2020-02-01")) %>%` before `ggplot`.
2. I removed `facet_grid(. ~ Species)` as it may not work with `facet_zoom`. Instead, I generated two separate graphs, and combined them using `ggarrange` from `ggpubr`. The code can be simplified but ideas are the same. Hope this helps.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

a_1 <- test %>%
  filter(Date >= as.Date("2019-07-01"), Date <= as.Date("2020-02-01"), 
         Species == "Montipora capitata"
         ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = (Date), y = ColorScore2, color = Bleach)) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = Bleach), fun = mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(aes(group = Bleach), fun = mean, geom = "line") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Bleach" = "gray", "Non-bleach" = "black")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Bleach" = "gray", "Non-bleach" = "black")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(title = "Montipora capitata")
b_1 <- a_1 + facet_zoom(xlim = c(as.Date("2019-09-16"), as.Date("2019-10-30")))

b_1
a_2 <- test %>%
  filter(Date >= as.Date("2019-07-01"), Date <= as.Date("2020-02-01"), 
         Species == "Porites compressa"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = (Date), y = ColorScore2, color = Bleach)) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = Bleach), fun = mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(aes(group = Bleach), fun = mean, geom = "line") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Bleach" = "gray", "Non-bleach" = "black")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Bleach" = "gray", "Non-bleach" = "black")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title = "Porites compressa")
b_2 <- a_2 + facet_zoom(xlim = c(as.Date("2019-09-16"), as.Date("2019-10-30")))
ggarrange(b_1, b_2, common.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]